# Path must not contain // in them

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I have made a social media app where users can upload there pic. I want to add a delete option for the users in the app. I want the users to delete their pic from Firebase cloud storage whenever needed. Here is my code

```
            val firebase_url = contentDTOs[p1].imageUrl
            val storageRef =
                firebase_url?.let { it1 ->
                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("images").document(
                        it1
                    )
                }




            storageRef?.delete()?.addOnSuccessListener {
                // File deleted successfully
                Toast.makeText(context , "Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }?.addOnFailureListener {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                Toast.makeText(context , "cannot delete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            return@setOnLongClickListener true
```

But whenever I try to delete any image it returns me an error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.videoapp, PID: 20522
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path (https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/video-app-af9bf.appspot.com/o/images%2FIMAGE_20201023_144632_.png?alt=media&token=9cd9d400-49ed-4f73-81b3-baa7668a8430). Paths must not contain // in them.
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but maybe try removing the `https://` from the URL? So URL would be `firebasestorage.googleapis...`

Comment: How will I remove it

Comment: I don't know, I'm really not familiar with Kotlin, but there must be some kind of string parser you can use to do it.

Comment: Yes contentDTOs[p1].image url is the parse here

Comment: You code is trying to delete a document from Firestore.  Is that what you want?  Or are you trying to delete a document from Cloud Storage, which is a different thing entirely?  Please edit the question to be clear about what your goal is.

Comment: I am trying to delete a document from cloud storage with its fields

Comment: Well, you are using Firestore's API.  That's not going to work at all.  You need to use the Cloud Storage API.

Comment: Yes I am using cloud storage

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have

> images%2FIMAGE_20201023_144632

fragment in your link. And %2F is encoded backslash. Unfortunately from your code is not clear, how this link is formed

Comment: I can't understand

Comment: Please look at the error message.  It says:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path (https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/video-app-af9bf.appspot.com/o/images%2FIMAGE_20201023_144632_.png?alt=media&token=9cd9d400-49ed-4f73-81b3-baa7668a8430). Paths must not contain // in them.
So valid link should be: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/video-app-af9bf.appspot.com/o/images/IMAGE_20201023_144632_.png?alt=media&token=9cd9d400-49ed-4f73-81b3-baa7668a8430.
But from a fragment of your code is not clear, how this link is created, so I can't suggest where is the issue